# x-editable (jQuery UI build) throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typeerror, x-editable

Consider the following code:

Inside jQuery *document.ready*:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$("#username").editable({
        send: 'never',
       success: function(response, newValue) {
        userModel.set('username', newValue); //update backbone model
       }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="editable">
     <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
</div>
```

This throws *Uncaught TypeError: this.tip(...).find is not a function* at *jqueryui-editable.js:4727*.

I assume this is because of incompatibilities with the jQuery UI version. But how can I get around it?

**Update: Adding full example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/jqueryui-editable/js/jqueryui-editable.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        $("#username").editable({
            send: 'never',
           success: function(response, newValue) {
            userModel.set('username', newValue); //update backbone model
        }
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="editable">
        <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing shown in question relating to jQuery UI. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I am using the jQuery UI build from [https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/). So yes, it is related.

Comment: understand it's related somehow but without being able to replicate this is hard to help

Comment: Now I have added a full example that you can run as a HTML file to replicate the error.

Comment: A dmoe should only contain the minimal amount needed to replicate the issue. That's a full copy of the docs not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Also better to use a sandbox like jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co where people can fork and change with the code

Comment: Well, this is the minimal amount, and by no means a 'full' copy of the docs. I have removed lots of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but solved it by using an older version of jquery-ui. I was on v 1.12.0, but noticed the editable demo used 1.10.1. Using the 1.10.1 version of jquery-ui allowed me to use editable.

I'm using

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

and

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: this solved the issue for me as well, thanks for providing these

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the source code specific to jqueryui 1.11.4. 
It doesn't look like the jquery version of the source code has been touched since 2013, so I don't think it'll be fixed anytime soon. Unfortunately this is the most functional inplace editing library I've found, so I was determined to make it work.

A decent alternative is to use the "plain" version of the library which doesn't use jqueryui at all. It appears to me to be functionally equivalent. If you want the "popup" instead of "inline" mode, you need to also grab and include [poshytip](http://vadikom.com/files/?file=poshytip/poshytip-1.2.zip)